# Sorting references alphabetically

Tags: bibtex, natbib, sorting

I am trying to use a modified (German) bibstyle from the *American Economic Review* (The original version can be downloaded from http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/economic/aer.bst. I have simply replaced "and" by "und", "Vol." by "Bd.", "eds."/"ed." by "Hrsg." and normal quotes with German ones. ). The references appear in the format:
"**Lastname, Firstname**" for the first author and "**Firstname Lastname**" for all others.

The ordering of the references should be by the authors' last names; however if I have two papers written by three authors with the same first author Bibtex arranges them in an incorrect order:

E.g. using Bibtex I get
Felbermayr, Gabriel J., Julien *Prat* und Hans-Jörg Schmerer ....

Felbermayr, Gabriel J., Mario *Larch* und Wolfgang Lechthaler ....

That is given that the first author is identical, Bibtex sorts the papers by the second author's first name. However, I would like it to show up as

Felbermayr, Gabriel J., Mario Larch und Wolfgang Lechthaler ....
Felbermayr, Gabriel J., Julien Prat und Hans-Jörg Schmerer ....

Moreover, I get a similar problem if there is one paper written by two authors and those very same authors have written another paper together with a third author. For instance, I get:

Helpman, Elhanan, Oleg Itskhoki und Stephen J. Redding... in front of

Helpman, Elhanan, und Oleg Itskhoki..., which is the wrong order.

Can anyone help me with this?

### MWE

`Test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[%
fontsize=12pt,                              % Schriftgr??e (12pt, 11pt (Standard))
titlepage,                      % Titelei auf eigener Seite
headings=small,         % Überschriften etwas kleiner (smallheadings)
]{scrartcl}


\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

%% Deutsche Anpassungen %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=40mm, right=20mm, bottom=20mm} 

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setromanfont{Times New Roman}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\usepackage{graphicx} %%Zum Laden von Grafiken
\usepackage{color}
\makeatletter 


\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%% Bibliographiestil %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{aer_german3}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}

\setlength{\footskip}{1cm}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{unicode-math} \setmathfont{XITS Math}


\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\begin{list}{}{%
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
\settowidth{\labelwidth}{00\@thefnmark}%
% ^^ Anzahl_Nullen =df. Abstand
\setlength{\labelsep}{0.7pt}%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
\addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
\footnotesize}\item[\@makefnmark\hfill]#1%
\end{list}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
TEXT \citep{Felbermayr.2011} \citep{Felbermayr.2013} \citep{HELPMAN.2010} \citep{Helpman.2010c}
\bibliography{BA2-MWE}
\end{document}
```

The files `aer-german3.bst` and `BA2-MWE.bib` can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/71fmndkmldoqi1x/AABrY_ES13iuU4LDNS_vON-Za?dl=0).

### **ADDITIONAL COMMENT: Using the original English bibstyle resolves the latter problem, but not the first one.**

By the way, I am using Texmaker together with MikTex

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx, and thank you for creating a MWE! It is always better to include the code samples in the question, so that the question doesn't become meaningless when a link expires. The files `BA2.bib` and `aer-german3.bst` are too long to be embedded here, so I kept the link for them. However, it looks like `BA2.bib` could be made "more minimal" by removing non-relevant entries. If `aer-german3.bst` can be found in an official repository somewhere, please include that link instead of a dropbox link.

Comment: Please post the codes for the various Helpman and Felbermayr entries; this will save a lot of typing and guesswork for those who might want to come up with an answer to your questions.

Comment: I have uploaded a reduced form of the BA2.bib (called) BA2-MWE.bib which only includes those references including Felbermayr or Helpman. For all of these, the mentioned problems are relevant.

Comment: The sorting is by first author and then by year, which makes more sense in an author-year reference system.

Comment: So is there any way to change the sorting to be by first author, second author etc. and then year?

Answer (score 1):

I had a look to your given files and found several errors there.

I will only list some of the errors here:

- In your `bib` file you wrote several times `year = {2011a},` or simular.  There is only a number allowed, the year.  The  `a` should you better write in the key, for example `@article{Felbermayr.2011a,`
- And so I changed in your tex code the `\cite` commands to use the corresponding cite keys.
- You mixed environments for `pdflatex` (`inputenc`) and  `xelatex` (`\setmainfont`). I commented the first one.
- Because in your german `bst` file version are so much errors I changed the style to the english style.  My answer here is late so I do not correct the german `bst` file if there is no need for that work. One remark: not all "and" can be changed to "und". Only the one enclosed with " " ... Most of the errors you got are caused in the faulty german version of the `bst` file ...
- I made your code shorter (deleted unused code for the preblem here) and used package `filecontents` to add the corrrected `bib` file into the mwe.
- I fixed some warnings because the `bst` file uses old commands `\bf` etc.
- I moved package `hyperref` to be the last called package.  You should rework the order of package calls ...

The following MWE compiles without error and only one warning (comming from `filecontents`, that's okay!):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Felbermayr.2013b,
 author  = {Felbermayr, Gabriel J. and Larch, Mario and Flach, Lisandra and 
           Yalcin, Erdal and Benz, Sebastian},
 year    = {2013},
 title   = {Dimensionen und Auswirkungen eines Freihandelsabkommens zwischen der EU und den USA},
 url     = {http://www.cesifo-group.de/DocDL/ifo\_AH\_2013\_TAFTA\_Endbericht.pdf},
 address = {M{\"u}nchen},
 urldate = {29/08/2014},
 series  = {Studie im Auftrag des Bundesministeriums f{\"u}r Wirtschaft 
            und Technologie --Endbericht},
 institution = {{ifo Institut}},
}

@article{Felbermayr.2013a,
 author = {Felbermayr, Gabriel J. and Larch, Mario and Lechthaler, Wolfgang},
 year   = {2013},
 title  = {Unemployment in an Interdependent World},
 pages  = {262--301},
 volume = {5},
 number = {1},
 issn   = {1945-7731},
 journal = {American Economic Journal: Economic Policy},
 doi    = {10.1257/pol.5.1.262},
}


@article{Felbermayr.2011a,
 author = {Felbermayr, Gabriel J. and Prat, Julien and 
           Schmerer, Hans-J{\"o}rg},
 year   = {2011},
 title  = {Globalization and Labor Market Outcomes: Wage Bargaining, 
           Search Frictions, and Firm Heterogeneity},
 pages  = {39--73},
 volume = {146},
 number = {1},
 issn   = {00220531},
 journal = {Journal of Economic Theory},
 doi    = {10.1016/j.jet.2010.07.004},
}


@article{Felbermayr.2011b,
 author = {Felbermayr, Gabriel J. and Prat, Julien and Schmerer, Hans-J{\"o}rg},
 year   = {2011},
 title  = {Trade and Unemployment: What Do the Data Say?},
 pages  = {741--758},
 volume = {55},
 number = {6},
 issn   = {00142921},
 journal = {European Economic Review},
 doi    = {10.1016/j.euroecorev.2011.02.003},
}


@article{HELPMAN.2010a,
 author = {Helpman, Elhanan and Itskhoki, Oleg},
 year   = {2010},
 title  = {Labour Market Rigidities, Trade and Unemployment},
 pages  = {1100--1137},
 volume = {77},
 number = {3},
 issn   = {00346527},
 journal = {Review of Economic Studies},
 doi    = {10.1111/j.1467-937X.2010.00600.x},
}

@article{Helpman.2010c,
 author = {Helpman, Elhanan and Itskhoki, Oleg and Redding, Stephen J.},
 year   = {2010},
 title  = {Inequality and Unemployment in a Global Economy},
 pages  = {1239--1283},
 volume = {78},
 number = {4},
 issn   = {0012-9682},
 journal = {Econometrica},
 doi    = {10.3982/ECTA8640},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[%
  fontsize=12pt,         % Schriftgr??e (12pt, 11pt (Standard))
  titlepage,             % Titelei auf eigener Seite
  headings=small,        % Überschriften etwas kleiner (smallheadings)
]{scrartcl}


%% Deutsche Anpassungen %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=40mm, right=20mm, bottom=20mm} 

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setromanfont{Times New Roman}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\usepackage{color}


%\usepackage{titlesec} % Warning with KOMA-Script


%% Bibliographiestil %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{aer}% aer_german3 aer
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}

\setlength{\footskip}{1cm}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{unicode-math} \setmathfont{XITS Math}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
TEXT 
\citep{Felbermayr.2011a} 
\citep{Felbermayr.2013a} 
\citep{HELPMAN.2010a} 
\citep{Helpman.2010c}
{
\let\it\itshape
\let\bf\bfseries
\bibliography{\jobname}
}
\end{document}
```